# Store temporary WAV files on local disk with Exact Audio Copy (EAC)

Tags: nas, flac, wav, local-storage, exact-audio-copy

Using EAC I am storing FLAC files on a NAS drive. EAC rips a WAV file first then creates a FLAC file and then deletes the WAV file. When selecting the NAS drive for storage of the FLAC files, the WAV files are stored there too. To cut down unnecessary network traffic I would like to store the WAV files on the local disk instead, using the NAS solely for FLAC files.

Is there a way of doing this already in the software, or should I put a feature request in with the developers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Under `EAC menu / EAC Options / Directories` set the WAV extraction directory to your local HDD:

   [image: 1]
2. Then go to `EAC menu / Compression Options / External Compression` and set it up as shown below:

   [image: 2]
   [image: 3]
3. Be sure to specify the full path to **Flac.exe** (#4) and set **Additional command-line options** (#5) to something like the following (use the [tags and other placeholders](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=EAC_placeholders) you prefer):

   ```
   -8 -V -T "TITLE=%title%" -T "ARTIST=%artist%" -T "ALBUMARTIST=%albumartist%" -T "ALBUM=%albumtitle%" -T "DATE=%year%" -T "TRACKNUMBER=%tracknr%" -T "TRACKTOTAL=%numtracks%" -T "GENRE=%genre%" -T "COMMENT=%comment%" -T "PERFORMER=%albuminterpret%" -T "COMPOSER=%composer%" %source% -o Drive:\Output_Path\%dest%
   ```

   The main thing to note here is the last parameter, i.e. **-o Drive:\Output_Path\%dest%**
   Set this path so that the encoded FLACs are stored on your NAS.

Comment: Unfortunately it fails due to enforced quotations i.e. `Z:\Music\"0tmp1!542.flac"` even with `-o Z:\Music\%dest%` and no quotations around `%dest%`.

Comment: Ah crap, it worked with Flac.exe from the command line so I didn't think about EAC adding quotes around the file name (though it makes sense obviously since they can contain spaces). I'll see if there's any way to strip the quotes. A possible workaround meanwhile might be to call Flac.exe indirectly. What I mean is, in the dialog above call a batch file and pass it %source% and %dest%. In the batch file call Flac.exe with the necessary params, including the output path prefixed to %dest%

Comment: BTW, I think I might report this to the devs. After all, none of the other params such as %title%, %artist% etc. contains quotes (they're all added explicitly), so why should %source% and %dest%? If the user needs to remember to add quotes around the other params (since they can contain spaces as well obviously), then %source% and %dest% shouldn't be treated any differently IMO.